# Tabbed Presenters updated Example

Tags: gwt-platform

I'm trying to implement tabbed presenters following the example (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/source/browse/gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-tab/), but, reading some classes javadoc, I see some differences... 
and could not implement a example like this, gotting various GIN errors like

```
Deferred binding result type PresenterA.CadastroPrefeituraProxy' should not be abstract
```

Is there a new example or new way to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your GIN binding: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6#Binding_everything_together. It's likely you forgot to bind the presenter, the view and the proxy.

Comment: Do you have a method to get the presenter in your ginjector? `AsyncProvider<PresenterA> getPresenterA();`.

Comment: anyway, I've implement tabbed presenters my own way, and it works. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error, the solution was to add **@ProxyCodeSplit** annotation to the Proxy interface:

```
@ProxyCodeSplit       // <-- this annotation was missing
@NameToken("!homePage")
@Title("Hooom")
public interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<HomePresenter> {
}
```

**or:**

(**@ProxyStandard** annotation is also ok if don't want code splitting, but in ClientGinjector, Provider should be used instead of AsyncProvider like:

```
Provider<HomePresenter> getHomePresenter();
```

> Note: using gwtp 0.7